# Can Redshift Spectrum Apply Partitioning Across Different Locations

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, aws-glue, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have a collection of parquet files that I am loading into redshift using a manifest file (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/loading-data-files-using-manifest.html).

I also want to apply partitioning to this data from faster queries from the data but since the data will be spread out among different locations, can I take advantage of partitioning?

For example say I have the following manifest to load data into Redshift Spectrum:

```
{
  "entries": [
    {"url":"s3://mybucket-alpha/location1/country=US/custdata1.parquet", "mandatory":true},
    {"url":"s3://mybucket-alpha/location2/country=US/custdata2.parquet", "mandatory":true},
  ]
}
```

For the data above is it possible to have a partition for country `US` and have it contain data from both locations?

Comment: Are you intending to load the data into Amazon Redshift using the `COPY` command, or are you intending to use Amazon Redshift Spectrum to query the data that is in S3 (_without_ loading it into the Redshift cluster)?

Comment: Redshift Spectrum will be used.